# passing props in vue js at compile time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm Mounting a htmlform elment and doing recompile.it takes some props. when i'm updating the props as listed below the Console throws these errors:-
 see the screenshot here
[image]

```
 <script>
     //some import over here

export default{
  props:['pma_posturl','pma_password','pma_username'],
  data: function(){
    return{
    domain:'',
    url:'',
    dbs:[],
    credentials:''
  }
},
methods:{
  //some functions to getting the credentials
  getcredentials(){

    this.popup();
  },
  popup(){

     //updating props value which vue js complains about  
     this.pma_username=this.credentials.database;
     this.pma_password=this.credentials.password;
     this.pma_posturl="URL"+this.credentials.database;

     console.log(this.pma_username); //has correct value
     this.compile('dbform',this.props);
     $('#myform').submit();
},

 compile: function(refs,props){
        var tmp = Vue.extend({
          props: props,
          template: '<form  method="post" :action="pma_posturl"  id = "myform" ref="myform" name="login_form" target="_blank"><input type="text" name="pma_username" id="input_username" :value="pma_username"><input type="password" name="pma_password" id="input_password" :value="pma_password"></form>'
        });
        new tmp().$mount(this.$refs[refs]);
      }
}
}

</script>
```

Comment: I do not see the point of setting up the component this way.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the following code :

```
    //updating props value which vue js complains about  
 this.pma_username=this.credentials.database;
 this.pma_password=this.credentials.password;
 this.pma_posturl="URL"+this.credentials.database;

 console.log(this.pma_username); //has correct value
 this.compile('dbform',this.props);
```

and create new object based on the `props` of the current component as follow :

```
  let customprops={
                  'pma_posturl':"URL"+this.credentials.database,
                  'pma_password':this.credentials.password,
                 'pma_username': this.credentials.database
               }

   this.compile('dbform',customprops);
```

Comment: The object customprops indeed is having the correct values. But my form template is still getting the empty value. is something wrong with my template definitions ?

Comment: try to console the props in the `mounted` hook of your template as follow :`mounted(){console.log(this.props)}` and see the resullt

Comment: `mounted(){console.log(this.props)}` ===>undefined                                            
`compile: function(refs,props){
..............................
console.log(props) ==> correct values
  new tmp().$mount(this.$refs[refs]);
      }`

Comment: so the problem is with your compile function, like eric99 said : 'I do not see the point of setting up the component this way'

Comment: My requirement is i have a input field and after getting submitted , i get some credentials and i do a post to the form which takes me to the external link in new tab.i'm adding the form in DOM at run-time and after submitting the form i remove it from the DOM. How do you guys suggest i should move forward.

Comment: so you wanna create a new component that wraps your form?

Comment: when you call `compile` method the form will be rendered or no?

Comment: it will be rendered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181019/discussion-between-boussadjra-brahim-and-rohit-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

I was passing the propsdata wrong. this is working .

```
compile: function(refs,props){
        var tmp = Vue.extend({
          props: ['pma_posturl','pma_password','pma_username'],
          template: '<form ......>........</form>'
        });
        new tmp({
        propsData: props
      }).$mount(this.$refs[refs]);
```

This is the code now. but it keeps picking up older values set on first call even i can console log the new value here.

```
 // console.log(props) /* it has the latest value */
 var vm = new tmp({propsData: props}).$mount(this.$refs[refs]);
 $('#myform').submit();
  vm.$destroy();
```

when i log the vm.$destory() ,i get undefined .what am i doing wrong here?